# na.fill for date showing the unexpected results

Tags: r, date, zoo

I tried to replace an `NA` na value in a date vector with another value using `zoo::na.fill`, but it replaced my `NA` value with "1970-01-02" rather than the value I specified:

```
library(zoo)
a <- as.Date(c(NA, '2018-01-01'))

na.fill(a, as.Date('2018-01-02'))
[1] "1970-01-02" "2018-01-01"
```

Why did it happen? Is it a bug or I need to specify something so that it can work as expected
  Note: I know that we can use `a[is.na(a)] <- as.Date('2018-01-02')` but this question is about `na.fill` in zoo

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.3/topics/as_date

Comment: Always a good idea to put things like `library(tidyverse)` and `library(lubridate)` in your sample code so that it will work when people cut and paste the code.

Comment: @ngm: or remove the code that would require dozens of package dependencies. :)

Comment: The development version of zoo now has `na.fill0` which does work in this case: `install.packages("zoo", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org"); 
na.fill0(a, as.Date('2018-01-02'))`   Ultimately, `na.fill` will call `na.fill0` (just as `na.locf` calls `na.locf0`) but it is expected that `na.fill0` will continue to be user accessible even after that just as `na.locf0` is user accessible.  Note that `na.fill0`, like `na.locf0`, only works on vectors, not matrices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## the beloved `zoo::na.*` functions

The zoo package is a wonderful source of functions for handling `NA` values, and they are widely used on non-`zoo` objects all the time, but they were written for time series with numeric values with an index. The behaviour of the `zoo::na.*` sometimes works as expected on non-numeric vectors, but sometimes not, as in the case of `zoo::na.fill` and a few others.

## overview of their behaviour on `Date` vectors

Some sample data. We use `zoo::as.Date` so I don't have to give an origin each time.

```
(a <- zoo::as.Date(c(10000, NA, 10002)))
#> [1] "1997-05-19" NA           "1997-05-21"
(b <- zoo::as.Date(10001))
#> [1] "1997-05-20"

zoo::na.aggregate(a) # As expected
#> [1] "1997-05-19" "1997-05-20" "1997-05-21"
zoo::na.approx(a) # Converts to numeric
#> [1] 10000 10001 10002
zoo::as.Date(zoo::na.approx(a)) # Workaround
#> [1] "1997-05-19" "1997-05-20" "1997-05-21"
zoo::na.fill(a, b) # Coerces b to logical TRUE then to numeric - see below
#> [1] "1997-05-19" "1970-01-02" "1997-05-21"
zoo::as.Date(zoo::na.fill(as.numeric(a), as.numeric(b))) # Workaround
#> [1] "1997-05-19" "1997-05-20" "1997-05-21"
zoo::na.locf(a) # As expected
#> [1] "1997-05-19" "1997-05-19" "1997-05-21"
zoo::na.spline(a) # Converts to numeric
#> [1] 10000 10001 10002
zoo::as.Date(zoo::na.spline(a)) # Workaround
#> [1] "1997-05-19" "1997-05-20" "1997-05-21"
zoo::na.trim(c(NA, NA, a, NA, NA)) # Converts to numeric
#> [1] 10000    NA 10002
zoo::as.Date(zoo::na.trim(c(NA, NA, a, NA, NA))) # Workaround
#> [1] "1997-05-19" NA           "1997-05-21"
```

## details of `zoo::na.fill` on `Date` vectors

In the source code for `na.fill.zoo` (which eventually does the work) there is this:

```
as.cls <- if (is.integer(coredata(object))) {
      as.integer
    }
    else if (is.numeric(coredata(object))) {
      as.numeric
    }
    else if (is.character(coredata(object))) {
      as.character
    }
    else {
      as.logical
    }
```

And `class(coredata(object))` is the same as `class(a)` which is `Date`. Since there is no `Date` option, `as.cls` defaults to `as.logical`.

The next thing that happens is the `fill` argument (essentially) has `as.cls` applied to it. In this case `fill` is a non-zero `Date`, which is coerced to the number `1` which is used to fill in the `NA`.

Then at the end the return value is coerced to the class of `object` which is date. And of course `as.Date(1)` is `1970-01-02`.

Comment: It makes sense that since zoo is for time series, so this function does not take time value into consideration. So we should stick to is.na to fill in this situation. Thanks alot

Comment: I suppose you are right. But the `zoo::na.*` functions are so convenient and widespread that they could very well be used on vectors more than on time series objects. Not the fault of the developers!